# Dar hover num elemento e mudar o outro não está a funcionar

Tags: html5, css3

Eu procurei por todas as formas de como dar `hover` num elemento e mudar outro e algumas delas já sabia e tinha tentando mas não estava a funcionar, então eu fui procurar por outras e eu tentei de tudo `#example:hover + #change`, `#example:hover ~ #change`, `#example:hover #change`, etc mas nenhum deles funcionou. Então eu fui pela solução mais fácil, `jQuery`, mas ele estava a bugar quando ele aplicava os efeitos, às vezes aplicava outras vezes não, tentei seguir com o css normal outra vez. Mas não encontrei jeitos!

**HTML**:

```
<div class="section">
     <img id="thumbnail" src="img.png">
     <h2 id="title"><center><span>Some title</span></center><h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#thumbnail:hover #title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Você quer esconder a imagem ao clicar em um botão? estou em duvida, me explique melhor

Comment: @PlanetWar você leu e viu o codigo? eu tou tentando dar hover na img e mudar o `#title` '-'

Comment: Entendi, um momento vou fazer o codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz em Js puro e deu certo, mas é muito mais viável fazer em css puro

Você fez certo, só precisava colocar um "+"

```css
#title {
    font-size: 100px;
}

#imagem:hover + #title {
    font-size: 10px
}
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" width="50" height"50">

<div id="title">Some title</div>
```